# Spring JPA repository how to write a query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `User` class, that is identified by id, and `Skills` class, that has its own id field, and also references `User`.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private SoftSkills softSkills;
}
```

the other one has

```
    @Entity
 public class SoftSkills {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;
}
```

Is there a simple way to write a query, implementing the `JPARepository`, that would search the `SoftSkills` class by using user.id field as a parameter and return a `SoftSkills` object as a result?

Comment: `List<SoftSkills> findByUserId(int id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, from the documentation:

> Property expressions can refer only to a direct property of the managed entity, as shown in the preceding example. At query creation time you already make sure that the parsed property is a property of the managed domain class. However, you can also define constraints by traversing nested properties. Assume a Person has an Address with a ZipCode. In that case a method name of

```
List<Person> findByAddressZipCode(ZipCode zipCode);
```

> creates the property traversal x.address.zipCode. The resolution algorithm starts with interpreting the entire part (AddressZipCode) as the property and checks the domain class for a property with that name (uncapitalized). If the algorithm succeeds it uses that property. If not, the algorithm splits up the source at the camel case parts from the right side into a head and a tail and tries to find the corresponding property, in our example, AddressZip and Code. If the algorithm finds a property with that head it takes the tail and continue building the tree down from there, splitting the tail up in the way just described. If the first split does not match, the algorithm move the split point to the left (Address, ZipCode) and continues.

So this will do the trick:

```
SoftSkills findByUserId(int id);
```

Reference; [Spring Data JPA Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: Yes, this does the trick :)
Can you point me to the documentation where you found the example?

Comment: I've added the link in my answer! If this worked for you please accept my answer.