# Spring JpaRepository how to query a @ManyToMany entity

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I had a similar issue yesterday, [how to write a query in JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176141/spring-jpa-repository-how-to-write-a-query), but now i have a different one. Classes User and Tag are @manyToMany dependent.

```
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@ManyToMany
private Set<UserTag> tags;
```

}

and UserTag:

```
@Entity
public class UserTag {

@ManyToMany
private Set<User> users;
```

}
Is there an easy way to write a query that would return all UserTags, based on a userID? I know i have the information in User, but if I create an public

```
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
```

then I can only get user objects, and not the tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get in the `UserRepository` other objects then `User`'s.

```
@Query("SELECT u.tags FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id")
public Set<UserTag> getUserTagsByUserId(@Param("id") int id);
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to do the job :) Thanks